Extending Logical Volume on RHEL 7
We're using a redhat 7. We tried to increase our storage with extending free space of an existing physical volume. You can find the screenshot and text output of it.
Output of "lsblk" command.
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   100G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0   400M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    0  97.7G  0 part
  ├─resilient-root    253:0    0   1.1T  0 lvm  /
  ├─resilient-swap    253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─resilient-co3     253:2    0 131.7G  0 lvm  /usr/share/co3
  └─resilient-var_log 253:3    0   155G  0 lvm  /var/log
sdb                     8:16   0   256G  0 disk
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   256G  0 part
  ├─resilient-co3     253:2    0 131.7G  0 lvm  /usr/share/co3
  └─resilient-var_log 253:3    0   155G  0 lvm  /var/log
sdc                     8:32   0   1.5T  0 disk
└─sdc1                  8:33   0   1.5T  0 part
  └─resilient-root    253:0    0   1.1T  0 lvm  /
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

When we extended our physical volume, "sdc" increased to 1.5 TB by itself. After that we tried to allocate this free space to "sdc1". Our reason of this action was increasing "resilient-root" size. We successfully increased size of sdc1 but we can't allocate this free space to "resilient-root".
I'm sharing some command outputs below as screenshots and texts.
Output of "vgdisplay" command.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               resilient
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  12
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               <1.35 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              352677
  Alloc PE / Size       352677 / <1.35 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0

Output of "lvdisplay" command. (I did not shared unnecessary output of this command.)
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/resilient/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                resilient
  LV UUID                
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time resilient.localdomain, 2019-11-15 19:17:04 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <1.06 TiB
  Current LE             277282
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0

We already tried command below but these commands are not working in our case.
 lvresize  --resizefs  --extents  +100%Free /dev/resilient/root
 lvextend -l +100%FREE  /dev/mapper/resilient-root
Thank you.

Add text, not images!

@RomeoNinov I added.

What is the filesystem of / ?

If the above commands worked, you stil need to resize the file system. For example resize2fs will do the trick for extX file systems.

@RomeoNinov xfs
@Powerriegel These commands not working. I can't allocate 400-500 GB to resilient-root directory. sdc 1.5 TB and I made somehow sdc1 from 1.1 TB to 1.5 TB but still can't increase resilient-root. That's my all problem.

@WWA, run command xfs_growfs /

@RomeoNinov it's not working. I ran xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/resilient-root and xfs_growfs / but both of them not working.

@WWA, any error, any result from the run? BTW did you run it as root?

vgdisplay shows there is no FREE space, so you either allocated the extra space to something else already or you never got it.

Your vgdisplay shows there is no FREE space, so you either allocated the extra space to something else already or you never got it increased.
The first thing you need to do after increasing the disk partition is also increasing the physical volume with pvresize.
After that, verify vgdisplay again to confirm you have extra space displayed as 'Free  PE / Size'.
After that you should be able to increase the logical volume with lvresize or lvextend.
As a final step you need to extend you filesystem.

Can you share commands for me step by step?
Because when I ran lsblk command, it seems "sdc" has 1.5 TB total storage. It was 1.1 before I add more space to that disk from VMware. I shutdown my device, I added more space and I switch on the device and I saw it extended to 1.5 TB from 1.1 TB. But "sdc1" was 1.1 still. After that I tried so many commands and "sdc1" increased to 1.5 TB but I can't extend my LV to 1.5 TB as you see output of my lsblk command.
My all problem is about extending LV for now. But if you say that I need to run another commands, please share them with me. Thanks.

You first need to extend the physical volume sdc1 using pvresize.
